# Excel sort list after string occurence

Tags: string, excel, sorting

I have a sheet in Excel 2013 with the following rows:

```
A113F01
A234D01
A233F01
A413G02
A412C01
A413D01
A114G01
A116D02
A333F02
A342G01
A233F03
A233G04
```

Is there a way to sort these rows, first after the number of occurrences of the 4 first characters in each row, then in ascending order so that the list looks like this:

```
A113D01
A113F01
A233F03
A233G04
A413D01
A413G02
A114G01
A116D02
etc....
```

Comment: I think example how data should look after sorting is not clear enough.

Comment: I just want the list to be sorted after the number of occurrences of the first 4 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a two step process where you would put a formula into an unused column to the right to count the frequency of the first four characters in column A with something like,

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, LEFT(A2, 4)&CHAR(42))
```

Put in the second row in the helper column and fill down to the bottom of the data in column A.

You would then sort using this new *helper* column as the primary sort key in descending order and column A as the secondary sort key in ascending order. Once sorted, keep or delete the data from the helper column as you prefer.

If you choose to go with a VBA-based solution, this would be a good place to start.

```
Sub sort_by_first_four()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            With .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                .Formula = "=COUNTIF(A:A, LEFT(A2, 4)&CHAR(42))"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 2)
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                            Key2:=.Columns(1), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            End With
            With .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                .ClearContents
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Data like the sample you provided usually has a column header and I've coded it like that. I've also assumed the data is in column A and that there is nothing in column B.

[image: Multiple Sort with Helper column]